# libxml inserted new node while reading

Tags: c, libxml2

I am trying to parse an xml file from my program. I am able to get the rootnode and print its name, property etc. successfully( No hardwork, only an api call :) ). But when I try to read its childnode and print its name, I am not getting what is there in the xml.

Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="UTF-8" ?>
<LanguageStats>
    <Languages>
        <Language name="C">
            <extensions key="c"/>
            <color key="\x1b[33m"/>
        </Language> 
    </Languages>
</LanguageStats>
```

Here is my C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>


#define XML_CFG_FILE "./lang_list.xml"

static void parse_xml(xmlNode* root_node)
{
    xmlNode *curr_node = NULL;

    if( root_node != NULL )
    {
        printf("\nRoot Element %s", root_node->name);
        curr_node = root_node->children;
        printf("\nCurrent Element %s", curr_node->name);
        curr_node = curr_node->children;
        if( !curr_node )
        {
            printf(" Something is wrong");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Root Element NULL");
    }
}

int main()
{
    xmlDoc *doc = NULL;
    xmlNode *root_element = NULL;

    LIBXML_TEST_VERSION 

    if( ( doc = xmlReadFile( XML_CFG_FILE, NULL, 0)) == NULL )
    {
        printf("error: could not parse file %s\n", XML_CFG_FILE);
        exit(-1);
    }

    root_element = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
    parse_xml(root_element);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this below output.

```
Root Element LanguageStats
Current Element text Something is wrong
```

When I change the logic to

```
printf("\nRoot Element %s", root_node->name);
curr_node = root_node->children;
printf("\nCurrent Element %s", curr_node->name);
curr_node = curr_node->next;
printf("\nCurrent Element %s", curr_node->name);
```

my output becomes

```
Root Element LanguageStats
Current Element text
Current Element Languages
```

My question is Am I missing something? or does libxml always work like that?. This is bugging me a lot and I am not able to solve this. Any small tips would be appreciated

Comment: There *is* a `text` node following `<LanguagStats>`. If you print its contents, you will find it contains a newline and a tab.

Comment: Is it standard for XML. Earlier I have used tinyxml for C++. In that I did not come across such things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured how to get the next Element. Here, I am attaching the code snippet

```
static xmlNode* GetNextNode(const xmlNode* node )
{   
    xmlNode* ret_node = node->next;

    while( ret_node )
    {
        /* Node has type XML_ELEMENT_NODE, if it has property to hold children */
        if( ret_node->type != XML_ELEMENT_NODE ) 
        {
            ret_node = ret_node->next;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Found element node %s\n", ret_node->name );
            break;
        }
    }   
    return ret_node;
}
```

This somehow worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I figured how to get the next Element. Here, I am attaching the code snippet

```
static xmlNode* GetNextNode(const xmlNode* node )
{   
    xmlNode* ret_node = node->next;

    while( ret_node )
    {
        /* Node has type XML_ELEMENT_NODE, if it has property to hold children */
        if( ret_node->type != XML_ELEMENT_NODE ) 
        {
            ret_node = ret_node->next;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Found element node %s\n", ret_node->name );
            break;
        }
    }   
    return ret_node;
}
```

This somehow worked for me.